# Can we do transpose of data in Azure Mapping Data Flow?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, powerquery, azure-databricks, azure-data-factory

I am using mapping data flow to implement my M query script in ADF. In M query there is two function one is Table.pivot and other one is Table.transpose.
Mapping data flow has the pivot transformation but not the transpose.
Can anyone tell me that can we do transpose of data in Azure mapping data flow or I need to use other things (Databricks, Spark SQL) except mapping data flow?

Transpose will rotate all rows into column and column into rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to transpose an Excel table like that:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Field #1: | Value 1 |
| Field #2: | Value 2 |
| Field #3: | Value 3 |

to

| Field1 | Field2 | Field3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 |

### Solution

[image]

#### SummaryHeader (Dataset Excel)

[image]

[image]

#### SanitizeSummaryHeader (Derived Column)

[image]

Regex: `regexReplace(HeaderNameRaw, "[^\\w]+", "")`

#### TransposeHeader (Pivot)

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### PruneSummaryHeader (Select)

[image]

Matching condition: `!endsWith(name,"Raw")`

#### ReduceSummaryHeader (Aggregate)

[image]

[image]

Name matches: `^(?!\bFileName\b).+$`

Answer (score 0):

According my experience, Data Flow can not transpose the data.

You need to use other actives or tools in code level.