# transpose data in azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Working on this since last 2 days
Unable to find a solution. Had tried 
approach 1 - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64940136/can-we-do-transpose-of-data-in-azure-mapping-data-flow)  
approach 2 - tried pivot point

This is Sample data in csv file, Which I need to transpose,  
[image]

The output I am trying is 
[image]

Any help is really appreciated , Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you maybe use a azure function activity to do it? Then you can write your own transpose transformation code.

Comment: Where is the data coming from and in what format is it? (.xlsx or .csv)  Where does it need to go to, and in what format?

Comment: @wBob The data is in csv fomat and the file is in blob storage, I need to save again in blob storage in csv format

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this task simply by writing a python code in Azure Function. You can use the same function in Azure Data Factory by using the AZure Function activity as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity).

Please find the below example where we are assuming the file is located in Azure Blob Storage, hence we are using [Azure Storage SDK for Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python).

To install this library, run the below command:

`pip install azure-storage-blob`

For transpose, we are using pandas library

To install this library, run the below command:

`pip install pandas`

Find the code sample below. Change the blob storage details as per your account details.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
import pandas as pd
import tables

STORAGEACCOUNTNAME= <storage_account_name>
STORAGEACCOUNTKEY= <storage_account_key>
LOCALFILENAME= <local_file_name>
CONTAINERNAME= <container_name>
BLOBNAME= <blob_name>

# download from blob
blob_service=BlockBlobService(account_name=STORAGEACCOUNTNAME,account_key=STORAGEACCOUNTKEY)
blob_service.get_blob_to_path(CONTAINERNAME,BLOBNAME,LOCALFILENAME)

# LOCALFILE is the file path
dataframe_blobdata = pd.read_excel(LOCALFILENAME, sheet_name="<Sheet_Name>")

# transpose the data
df_transposed = dataframe_blobdata.T

# print the transposed data
print(df_transposed)
```

Comment: Hi @UtkarshPal-MT, where do need to install the libraries using pip? Is it from Azure portal or like start task in batch acticity or somewhere ? Please guide.

Comment: you can link your azure account with visual code and create azure function using python language. Then, using terminal you can install packages using pip command. follow https://arinti.ai/how-to-installing-modules-in-a-python-azure-function/

Comment: Thanks for that link, however in the last line I see that "but in some cases you will still get an error because OpenCV and NumPy are just installed locally and not on Azure." How do I install packages in azure instance